# TailwindCSS classes arent showing up (React) when deployed via Netlify, where did I go wrong?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, tailwind-css, netlify

Hi Ive been racking my brain on what Ive been doing wrong. Locally the formatting is correct, but when I push it to Netlify, Tailwindcss decides to not work. Am I purging wrong? I have a tailwind css file in my `dist` and `src` folders. [image]

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "bgg_version_3",
  "keywords": [
    "design, graphic design, art, illustration, web design, Virginia, Massachusetts, Boston, Newport News"
  ],
  "homepage": ".",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.2",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.1.0",
    "next": "^11.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.4",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-tsparticles": "^1.33.2",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
"scripts": {
    "build:tailwind": "tailwindcss build -i src/tailwind.css -o src/tailwind.output.css",
    "prestart": "npm run build:tailwind",
    "prebuild": "npm run build:tailwind",
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sass": "^1.36.0"
  }
}
```

## tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", './src/*.{scss,css}',"./src/components/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}","./src/components/*.{scss,css}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Any clue as to why it wont seem to work when deployed or what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Normally the devDependecies in your package.json would look somthing like this when using tailwindcss:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.1",
    "postcss": "^8.3.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.7" 
}
```

So I would suggest you redo the process of installing tailwindcss and remember the `--save` flag on every install

Comment: I installed them. I didnt know they were supposed to show up there. Its still not displaying correctly deployed as it is locally. Any ideas?